# Why the state variable doesn't change in certain parts of this Swift code?

Tags: swiftui

I'm having a hard time to understand the code below. If you look at my comments, I'm trying to change a binding variable in different parts of the code, but it's only working in the WKWebView events functions in the Coordinator.

Why doesn't the variable change when I try to do so in other parts of the code?

```swift
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import PlaygroundSupport

struct InternalBrowser: NSViewRepresentable {
    var webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()
    @Binding var status: String
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        // THIS WON'T CHANGE THE BINDING VARIABLE
        self.status = "makeNSView"
        return self.webView
    }
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: InternalBrowser
        init(parent: InternalBrowser) {
            self.parent = parent
            
            // THIS WON'T CHANGE THE BINDING VARIABLE
            self.parent.status = "Coordinator:: init"
        }
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            // THIS WORKS
            self.parent.status = "LOADING"
        }
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            // THIS WORKS
            self.parent.status = "LOADED"
        }
    }
}

struct Browser: View {
    @State var status = "STATUS"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            InternalBrowser(status: self.$status).frame(width: 400, height: 400)
            Text(self.status)
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(Browser().frame(width: 500, height: 500))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't the variable change when I try to do so in other parts of the code?

`@Binding` affects corresponding `@State` which itself results in corresponding View rebuild, but(!) `NSViewRepresentable.makeNSView` and `Coordinator.init` are called during(!) View rebuild... so, changing state during view rebuild cause new view rebuild, which comes to new change of state... cycle. Such situations are handled by SwiftUI rendering engine and ... such state changes are ignored. This is what you see.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation makes sense. I think it's such an easy mistake to make that I wished the compiler issued a warning.

Comment: Rending is run-time process... so you can meet such warning - "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior." - this is it.